# ICANN collision in chrome, view source works

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, homestead

So, I've just created a new site on Laravel Homestead. I pretty much always use .app as my local tld, and I've not had a problem with it before.

I've just created 2 new ones in my `homestead.yaml` file:

```
admin.philcross.app
philcross.app
```

I've run `vagrant reload --provision` and verified it's in my `/etc/hosts` file. Both domains are, and point to my VM.

If I go to philcross.app, it works. I see the webpage. If I go to admin.philcross.app, it fails, tells men There's an ICANN collision. However if I view the source, I see my webpage source. Not the error source.

To make it even more weirder, I already use a couple of local other domains locally exactly like the above (for example `subdomain.domain.app` locally). And it works.

The `admin.philcross.app` domain also works in Firefox.

I'm using Chrome, on Ubuntu 16.10.
I've tried altering the order of the domain mapping in my `homestead.yaml` file (ie putting `admin.philcross.app` before `philcross.app` and vice versa`).
I've tried multiple times`vagrant halt / vagrant up / vagrant reload --provision / vagrant provision`
I've tried opening my hosts file with sudo and saving

Does anyone else have any ideas? I'm completely stuck, and all googling so far has just said to put the subdomain in the homestead.yaml file (not helpful).

[image: WTF Chrome]

Comment: have you updated your hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.app` is a real TLD, owned by Google.](https://www.registry.google/about/domains.html) It isn't open for registrations yet, but it is likely to become available soon; your browser is warning you that your domain is likely to conflict with a real domain in the near future.

Don't use `.app` for internal applications or development, even locally. (Don't use `.dev` either; it, too, is a real TLD that belongs to Google!) Use one of the four top-level domains that has been explicitly and permanently reserved for testing:

- `.test`
- `.example`
- `.invalid`
- `.localhost`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks for the explanation :) Changing to .test works fine, and the explantion given was helpful as well, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

map your sites to same root:

```
sites:
    - map: philcross.app
      to: /home/vagrant/philcross/public
    - map: admin.philcross.app
      to: /home/vagrant/philcross/public
```